irlba and Matrix incompatibility in R
I am getting the below error when I try to set an nv value in the below code. When I leave the nv argument out, the block runs fine. The problem but I need to actually set a value for this for my work.
word_vectors <- tidy_pmi %>%
    widely_svd(
        item1, item2, pmi, nv = 50)

### leaving nv out fixes this

Error in irlba::irlba(m, nv = nv, ...) : 
  function 'as_cholmod_sparse' not provided by package 'Matrix'


I am also aware there may be some compatibility between the irlba and Matrix package, but I cannot seem to fix this.
I have tried reinstalling both irlba and Matrix from source with no luck.

There are a few more suggestions you can try here https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues/8100
